# I want to map a network share on a computer

Tags: windows, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I want to map a remote harddisk on my computer

Say I have a computer A which has a external HDD on F:

I want to mount F: on my computer B

I tried net use \ComputerA\F$ /user:UsernameA PasswordA
Also How can i use powershell for it

Comment: you can use net use from the powershell, otherwise look at `new-psdrive` and the correct syntax for net use is `net use \\servername\share`

Comment: Its acuatlly a pen drive which i want to access

Comment: This is not a problem as long as you share it

Answer (score 1):

if you have access to the remote machine you can use the [psexec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) command to share the drive on the remote machine and then use net use to map it on your local machine

```
psexec \\remotePC net share f$=f:
net use \\remotePC\f$
```